# 100Mb X.odt file on my computer converted to a 20Kb X.odt folder

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice

recently a 100Mb X.odt file on my computer converted to a 20Kb X.odt FOLDER!!
i made that file years ago via microsoft word and recently edited it with libreoffice in linux
is there anything related about word and libreoffice misconfiguration?!
also when i double click on the X.odt folder it open the current directory again!!

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound good.
This can't happen due to some sort of bad configuration. The last time the file was written/opened something got seriously messed up on your harddisk which corrupted the file.

The first thing to do is run a full disk check on that disk to make sure the filesystem is still consistent and repair it if needed. (Probably needed because a folder wouldn't refer back to its parent under normal circumstances.)

After that is done you may have the file back, but more likely it will be lost. You do have a backup I hope?

Comment: yes i did, i have a backup of 'em
i think so that something serious happened to my HDD cuz recently i lost another important file again!!!
how do u prefer me to check disk in linux?

Comment: @Raul In Linux the command-line command is "fsck". You will have to Google a bit to find instructions how to use it on your specific Linux distribution. But I would strongly recommended to download the GParted live-CD/USB and boot from that. Then, from that live-system, you can scan (and repair if needed) your main system without your running OS (running from the suspect disk) getting in the way.

Comment: tnx buddy
i did it, really hope it fixed